# How to arrange in alphabetical order by maiden name but include married name

Tags: lists, sort-ordering

In a class list, what is the correct way to arrange in alphabetical order by maiden name but also include married name, so that someone who doesn't know the person and does not know the list is in alphabetical order by maiden name would be able to tell which is which?

Answer (score 4):

Put the married name in parentheses after the first name with "now" in front of it.  In last name, first name form:

```
Anderson, Anne (now Barlow)
Atler, Stacia (now Ruger)
Bandon, Michael
Candlish, Maria (now Candlish-McCarthy)
```

In first name, last name form:

```
Anne Anderson (now Barlow)
Stacia Atler (now Ruger)
Michael Briar
Maria Candlish (now Candlish-McCarthy)
```

If you want to appear slightly more traditional, but make your sort order more obscure, use "née" in the inverse formation.  This is especially obscure in last name, first name form, so I hesitate to recommend it if that's what you're using:

```
Barlow, Anne (née Anderson)
Ruger, Stacia (née Atler)
Bandon, Michael
Candlish-McCarthy, Maria (née Candlish)
```

It's fairly sensible in first name, last name form:

```
Anne Barlow (née Anderson)
Stacia Ruger (née Atler)
Michael Bandon
Maria Candlish-McCarthy (née Candlish)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. I'd add the word *now* though, just to make it clearer: `Anderson, Anne (now Barlow)`

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Good thought.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I've edited my answer to incorporate your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: Note the "nee" form is standard and, if the reader doesn't recognize it, they could look it up. The "now" form is not standard, though the intent looks pretty clear to me.